# Conditional formatting on list based on a user/person/AD entity

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

I have found many how-to guides on JavaScripts to render a colored line in a SP list based on a word in some column. I tried it with a 'person' (a people column) and it did not work.

The value in question is the `NOTAPPROVED` (tried with all type of combinations) which is an entry in AD.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('notapproved')"); $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#F5A9A9");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following selector worked for me:

```
$('td.ms-vb-user a:contains(NOTAPPROVED)').closest('tr').css('background-color', '#f5a9a9');
```

User fields do not get the ms-vb2 class applied to them (at least not in my views in O365).

Comment: just for my personal knowledge, is there a site where I could have read this? A javascript tutorial site or similar? where do I read to understand the meaning of . closest('tr') etc?

Comment: jQuery has excellent [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).  You can find information on `.closest()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).  I'm fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery. A lot of what I learn is from these stack exchange sites.

Comment: can you help me on my other thread where i also put a screenshot? it is the same list and i am not able to highlight negative currencies

Comment: I posted an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `:contains` is case sensitive. If the value in the column is `NOTAPPROVED` then you need to do this:

```
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('NOTAPPROVED')");
```

Comment: I did it and it did not work, I wrote not approved in different ways just to highlight it. I have also tried with a normal name written exactly how it was displayed and it did not work. I am wondering if it is a 'person' field it needs to be written differently. I have also written it as it is created as account in AD with no success.

Comment: Are you sure your selector is correct? Try `$Text = $("td[class='ms-vb-user']:contains('NOTAPPROVED')");`. Your next line should also be this, to be safer: `$Text.closest("tr").css("background-color", "#F5A9A9");`